# How to assert a value within a span?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

How to assert a dynamic text value within a span using Within assertion method? I would like to check that value

```
<span class="FilterHeader--results--count">
    78
</span>
```

is within some range (for example 0 to 100).

Answer (score 3):

Use the [addCustomDOMProperties](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/extending-selectors.html#custom-properties) method for your case. It is better than [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288625/how-to-assert-a-value-within-a-span#answer-56291837) solution because in this case the [smart assertion query mechanism](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/#smart-assertion-query-mechanism) will work correctly.

```js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `fixture`;


test('test', async t => {
    const span = Selector('.FilterHeader--results--count').addCustomDOMProperties({
            integerSpanValue: el => parseInt(el.innerText, 10)
    });

    await t.expect(span.integerSpanValue).within(0, 100);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the text in the span to a number, and then assert that the value is between 0 and 100 (inclusive). There's also a similar example under [the Within section in the documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/assertion-api.html#within).

```js
await t
    .expect(parseInt(await Selector('span.FilterHeader--results--count').innerText)).within(0,100);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I get this result:  AssertionError: expected NaN to be within 0..100

Comment: @JakubSip try adding an await before Selector (e.g. parseInt(await Selector('...')). Probably trying to parse the promise.

Comment: Works! Thank you!